# differences between "d = dict()" and "d = {}"

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, timing

```
$ python2.7 -m timeit 'd={}'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0331 usec per loop
$ python2.7 -m timeit 'd=dict()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.19 usec per loop
```

Why use one over the other?

Answer (score 62):

I'm one of those who prefers words to punctuation -- it's one of the reasons I've picked Python  over Perl, for example.  "Life is better without braces" (an old Python motto which went on a T-shirt with a cartoon of a smiling teenager;-), after all (originally intended to refer to braces vs indentation for grouping, of course, but, hey, braces are braces!-).

"Paying" some nanoseconds (for the purpose of using a clear, readable short word instead of braces, brackets and whatnots) is generally affordable (it's mostly the cost of lookups into the built-ins' namespace, a price you pay every time you use a built-in type or function, and you can mildly optimize it back by hoisting some lookups out of loops).

So, I'm generally the one who likes to write `dict()` for `{}`, `list(L)` in lieu of `L[:]` as well as `list()` for `[]`, `tuple()` for `()`, and so on -- just a general style preference for *pronounceable* code.  When I work on an existing codebase that uses a different style, or when my teammates in a new project have strong preferences the other way, I can accept that, of course (not without attempting a little evangelizing in the case of the teammates, though;-).

Comment: "hoisting some lookups out of loops" - what this mean?

Comment: @Tshepang, e.g. instead of `for i in x: f(dict())` (which does `len(x)` lookups for name `dict`), first bind a local `d=dict` outside the loop, then `for i in x: f(d())` which does a faster _local_ lookup for name `d`). It's a fundamental Python technique to optimize some loops when they're proven (by profiling, of course) to be performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Incidentally (and not related to this question at all, of course), Unladen Swallow should make this kind of idiom (d=dict) unnecessary :)

Comment: @AlexMartelli What about `s=str()` vs. `s=''`?

Comment: I wouldn't use `str()` in lieu of `''` any more than `int()` in lieu of `0` -- that wouldn't promote "pronounceable code" nor reduce punctuation.

Comment: In addition to readability I also don't like that there is no sort of `{}` idiom for empty sets, so there is an uncomfortable asymmetry going on there. For empty collections, you have `[]` for `list()`, `{}` for `dict()`, and even `()` for `tuple()`, but nothing like that for `set()`.

Comment: You can't have a diploid punctuation character for every complex type! dict list and tuple are the core types that are supported. But I think I feel that dict() vs braces is somehow more Pythonic because it minimises language elements, so I empathise, but given these are the 3 most common ubiquitous complex types, and there is a 5x speed improvement, I prefer to use braces. How you can think making a local reference with d=dict improves readability or simplicity I don't know. Just use braces!

Answer (score 24):

`d=dict()` requires a lookup in [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) then [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) then `__builtins__`, `d={}` doesn't

Comment: Nope, `dict` is in `__builtin__`.

Comment: @MikeGraham yes but in most cases `__builtins__` is an alias for `__builtin__`

Answer (score 10):

If people use (just) `dict()` over (just) `{}`, it's generally because they don't know about `{}` (which is quite a feat), or because they think it's clearer (which is subjective, but uncommon.)

There are things you can do with `dict` that you can't do with `{}`, though, such as pass it to something that expects a callable, like `collections.defaultdict(dict)`. There's also the fact that you can call `dict` with keyword arguments, which some people prefer:

```
>>> dict(spam=1, ham=2)
{'ham': 2, 'spam': 1}
```

Personally, I prefer the dict literal syntax because it works better when you want to use keys that are not valid identifiers:

```
>>> dict(pass=1)
 File "<stdin>", line 1
    dict(pass=1)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> dict('ham and eggs'=1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

(and mixing styles just because some keys are not valid identifiers, yuck.)

Answer (score 7):

Doug Hellmann wrote up an exhaustive [comparison](https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/) of the performance difference.

**tl;dr**

> With CPython 2.7, using dict() to create dictionaries takes up to 6
>   times longer and involves more memory allocation operations than the
>   literal syntax. Use {} to create dictionaries, especially if you are
>   pre-populating them, unless the literal syntax does not work for your
>   case.

Answer (score 1):

Like Thomas said, I use dict() so I can specify keywords. Especially if I'm manually constructing a large dictionary for data initialization or whatnot: being able to use keyword syntax saves me two keystrokes (and the associated visual clutter) for every element.