# Creating an empty list in Python

Tags: python, performance, list, coding-style, timeit

What is the best way to create a new empty list in Python?

```
l = []
```

or

```
l = list()
```

I am asking this because of two reasons:

1. Technical reasons, as to which is faster. (creating a class causes overhead?)
2. Code readability - which one is the standard convention.

Comment: "faster"?  Why didn't you run timeit?

Answer (score 352, accepted):

Here is how you can test which piece of code is faster:

```
% python -mtimeit  "l=[]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0711 usec per loop

% python -mtimeit  "l=list()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.297 usec per loop
```

However, in practice, this initialization is most likely an extremely small part of your program, so worrying about this is probably wrong-headed.

Readability is very subjective. I prefer `[]`, but some very knowledgable people, like Alex Martelli, prefer `list()` because [it is pronounceable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745008/differences-between-d-dict-and-d/2745292#2745292).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the profiling. I had always wanted to know how it was done.

Comment: Why does `list('')` give `[]` instead of `['']`?

Comment: This is because this func make list from iterable types, you couldnt insert in more than 1 argument. (Try to type `list('abcd')` and you understand everything)

Answer (score 143):

`list()` is inherently slower than `[]`, because

1. there is symbol lookup (no way for python to know in advance if you did not just redefine list to be something else!),
2. there is function invocation,
3. then it has to check if there was iterable argument passed (so it can create list with elements from it) ps. none in our case but there is "if" check

In most cases the speed difference won't make any practical difference though.

Comment: +1: It feels good to understand why `list()` is slower than `[]`!

Comment: In the case of `list()` it has only to check if there was any arg at all ... "check if iterable" and "create list with elements" just don't happen; they only apply if there is an arg. It's even possible that the C code for `[]` calls the same C code as `list()`. In any case the time involved in (c) would be tiny compared with (a) + (b).

Comment: @John Machin - sorry for confusion, what i meant in (c) was that it will need to check if there was argument, yes. the rest was about what will happen if there were argument, which in our case there is none

Answer (score 18):

I use `[]`.

1. It's faster because the list notation is a short circuit.
2. Creating a list *with* items should look about the same as creating a list without, why should there be a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know about it, but it seems to me, by experience, that jpcgt is actually right. Following example: If I use following code

```
t = [] # implicit instantiation
t = t.append(1)
```

in the interpreter, then calling t gives me just "t" without any list, and if I append something else, e.g.

```
t = t.append(2)
```

I get the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'". If, however, I create the list by

```
t = list() # explicit instantiation
```

then it works fine.

Comment: It's because `t.append(1)` modifies `t` in place , it doesn't return anything but `None` and you are assigning this `None` to `t`. So `t` refers now to `None` instead of to the list. Your mistake here was to write `t=t.append(1)` instead of just `t.append(1)`. You'll notice the same behaviour with `list()`, so there`s no difference here.

Comment: And to be clear, @jpcgt's deleted post (that claimed `def f(lst=[]):` behaved differently from `def f(lst=list()):` in terms of avoiding default argument aliasing) was flagrantly wrong in its claims. Every claim you've made here is either 1) Wrong, or 2) Wholly irrelevant to the question.