# creating list of empty lists - Python

Tags: python

```
test = [[None for e in range(1)] for e in range(len(foobar)/2)]
for delete in range(0,len(test)):
        del test[delete][0]
```

This is not the most pythonic way to create an `empty list`

would you suggest something else?

I know that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972212/creating-an-empty-list-in-python) explains it. but this is not a duplicate of the previous one as you can see.

Comment: What's wrong with just test = [] ?

Comment: I think @pistal wants a list of empty lists.

Comment: @Brionius: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
test = [[] for e in range(len(foobar)/2)]
```

It has the same output as your code

Comment: @pistal: This would create a list containing ten references to the same list object.  If you added anything to any of the ten lists, it appears to be added to all of them, since they are all the same object.

Comment: Doesn't the question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size> contradict that or maybe i am wrong.
It says you can create lists that way.

Comment: @pistal Also `[]*10` concatenates an empty list with itself 10 times, which results in...an empty list.  `[[]]*10` is a little closer, but it has the problem that @SvenMarnach describes.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = [[None for e in range(1)] for e in range(len(foobar)/2)]
```

can be simplified to:

```
test = [[] for i in xrange(len(foobar)/2)]
```

Also don't forget to use `xrange` instead of `range`, as it returns a generator and not a complete list

Comment: Also, FYI, I recently learned this from a SO comment, so I'll pass it along, that `range` returns a generator object starting in python 3.

Comment: Yeah, but how shall i know he's not using python 3.3?

Comment: Oh, you wouldn't, and it's not a criticism, just a note.

Comment: And I meant iterator, not generator.

Answer (score 0):

An empty list:

```
test = []
```

Unless we're missing something ;-)

Or you want an list of empty lists of a given length?

```
n = 100
test = [ [] for i in range(0,n) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = map(lambda x: [], foobar[:len(foobar)/2])
```