# Simple Python console program asking questions

Tags: python

I'm trying to create this program

- Print a welcome message, and then prompt the user to select a difficulty by entering 1, 2 or 3.
- Use a loop to re-prompt the user until a valid response (1, 2 or 3) is entered.

Once a difficulty has been selected, print a message confirming the selected difficulty and set variables as follows:

- 1 was chosen:
  *lives* = 3, *max_num* = 10 and *questions* = 5
- 2 chosen:
  *lives* = 2, *max_num* = 25 and *questions* = 10
- 3 was chosen:
  *lives* = 1, *max_num* = 50 and *questions* = 15

**lives** represents how many incorrect answers are permitted.
**max_num** represents the largest number enter code here used when generating a question.
**questions** represents the number of questions

The code below is what i have done so far

```
def input_valid_difficulty(prompt=''):
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input(prompt))
            if n < 0 or n > 3:
                raise ValueError
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid choice! Enter 1,2 or 3.")
            prompt = "Select a difficulty?: (0 to exit):"
    return n

difficulty = input_valid_difficulty ("Select a difficulty?: (0 to exit):")
if difficulty == 0:
    quit()
elif difficulty == 1:
    print("Easy mode selected!")
elif difficulty == 2:
    print("Medium mode selected!")
elif difficulty == 3:
    print("Hard mode selected!")
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  Seems you could set lives and max_num based upon difficulty returned.

Comment: can you elaborate please.

Comment: Seems in you "elif" conditionals (where you have the print statements) you could set lives and max_num to the desired values to give you what you want.  Am I missing something?

Comment: yes sorry. its meant to be a math game which will allow the user to answer math equations. i need the end product to look like: Welcome to test. Select difficulty.' user selects easy' and after that i need the game to go straight in "question 1 of 5. you have 3 lives remaining. What is 5-3? User gives answer and gets a response either its correct or incorrect.

Comment: Posted a possible implementation of your game.

Comment: Was it clear how I generated the total list of questions as (question, answer) tuples and then randomly selected a subset of these questions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to better understand what you asking, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message or problem you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of generating a game you descibed.

```
from random import sample

def input_valid_difficulty(prompt=''):
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input(prompt))
            if n < 0 or n > 3:
                raise ValueError
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid choice! Enter 1,2 or 3.")
            prompt = "Select a difficulty?: (0 to exit):"
    return n

# Setup Difficult & Lives
difficulty = input_valid_difficulty ("Select a difficulty?: (0 to exit):")
if difficulty == 0:
    quit()
elif difficulty == 1:
    print("Easy mode selected!")
    lives, max_num, questions = 3, 10, 5
elif difficulty == 2:
    print("Medium mode selected!")
    lives, max_num, questions = 2, 25, 10
elif difficulty == 3:
    print("Hard mode selected!")
    lives, max_num, questions = 1, 50, 15

# Following line generates a list of 800 questions to choose from
operations = ['+', '-']  # testing addition and subtraction

#all_q_and_a = [(f"{i} {op} {j} = ?: ", eval(f"{i} {op} {j}")) for i in range(20) \
#                      for j in range(20) for op in operations]
# Following equivalent to above list comprehension
all_q_and_a = []
for i in range(20):
  for j in range(20):
    for op in operations:
      all_q_and_a.append((f"{i} {op} {j} = ?: ", eval(f"{i} {op} {j}")))

# Select random questions from list of all questions at random (note: 'questions' tells us how many questions to ask)
# 'Sample' selects a random list of unique questions from complete list
chosen_q_and_a = sample(all_q_and_a, questions)

# We now have a random set of questions and answers to present to 
# the user.  An example would be:
# [('18 + 19 = ?: ', 37), ('4 + 12 = ?: ', 16), ('8 + 2 = ?: ', 10), ('4 - 2 = ?: ', 2), ('1 + 3 = ?: ', 4)]

score = 0
for q in chosen_q_and_a:
  if lives == 0:
    break
  while lives > 0:
    answer = int(input(q[0]))
    if answer == q[1]:
      print("Correct")
      score += max_num  # increase score according to max_num 
                        #(wasn't sure if there was any
                        #other use of this variable)
      break
    else:
      lives -= 1
      print("Sorry, try again")

print(f"Your score was {score}")
```

Comment: i am receiving a error for all q_and_a= line, the error is on the 'for i  in range''

Comment: You're probably missing the continuation line indicator. Can you see and test the code here: https://repl.it/repls/SelfassuredIntentionalUsernames

Comment: Could be because i am using windows?

Comment: So am I.  Does the link I provided work?  That's on a cloud server and just uses your browser so it won't matter what you're on.  If that works you can try on your machine with  Jupyter notebooks, Pycharm, Visual Studio, etc.

Comment: You just have to hit the "run" button (greenish color) towards the top middle of the screen to run it.

Comment: it runs fine on there. why wouldn't it run on mine?

Comment: I replaced the triple long continuation line with a three lines for a triple for loop.  You can see if this works better for you.

Comment: all_q_and_a = list()
I made that change and it started working on my one. However it works for choice 2 and choice 3 but does not work for choice 1.

Comment: @RoryBreaker What error do you get for choice 1?  Also not sure why changing from (1) all_q_and_a = [], to (2) all_q_and_a = list() would make any difference.  They should be the same except (1) is faster per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972212/creating-an-empty-list-in-python.

Comment: yeah it works, spelling error is what was holding me back.

Comment: Hooray!!! By the way do you see how you can add additional operations such as multiply (i.e. ops = ['+', '-', '*']).  Or, you can replace with your own question entirely by creating your own all_q_and_a of the same structure.