# How do I move values of one list to another list

Tags: python

I want to move the data from one list to another list to create a backup variable. I am currently using the code below but it seems to clear list1 for some reason too. If someone can explain the reasoning behind this and help me with a solution, I would be very grateful. I am new to python but I have some programming knowledge from Java.

```
list1 = list2
list2.clear()
```

Comment: How about `list1 = list2` and then `list2 = []`?

Comment: You never actually made a copy of `list2` you just created a reference to it and called it `list1`

Comment: @It_is_Chris Thanks for explaining the reason.

Comment: @hc_dev My point is what I also commented under the answer: I doubt that they actually need a copy, so making one would be unnecessarily inefficient. Also, it was somewhat of a reply to an earlier comment that said "How about <some way to make a copy>".

Comment: @KellyBundy is right! __Comparative reasoning__:
 In Java `list2 = list1; list2.clear();` equally results in _same_ empty list (because both vars hold references to a single instance). To [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17873384) or [tag:clone] in Python: `list2 = list1[:]`. The consecutive [clearing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/850795) `list2.clear()` effects same as [creating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2972212) a fresh _new instance_ `list2 = []`.
 Similar to Java's `list2 = new ArrayList<?>()` instead `list2 = list1.clone(); list2.clear();` (where `?` is desired type). Clear ? ️

Answer (score -1):

The Python tutorial on W3Schools [Copy Lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_copy.asp) may help.

In Python you can *copy* [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=copy#list) instances using `my_list = my_other_list.copy()`. This will create a copy of the list.

But why don't we just assign the list to a variable like `my_list = my_other_list`? That's because we would only point to the original list thus not creating a copy.

See also: [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Comment: You should at least explain instead link-only - e.g.: Issue is when invoking `list2.clear()` which is executed on the reference, thus on `list1` actually. To solve _copy_ and create a new list like `list2 = list1.copy()` ( instead assigning the reference ).

Comment: Since they apparently weren't aware that there can be multiple references to the same list, I suspect they don't have any other references to it. In that case, it's more efficient to **not** make a copy and instead make `list2` a new list with `list2 = []`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm dumb, I wrote clone instead of copy

Comment: [tag:clone] is a similar concept and conventional name of (instance-)methods to copy an object (in C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, etc.).

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with w3? I kinda like them when learning + docs. What do you use?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with [w3](https://www.w3.org/). One of the things wrong with w3**schools** is that *"They've chosen a name that misleads people into thinking they're affiliated with the W3C"* (quote from one of the answers [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-wrong-with-W3Schools-that-it-is-often-referred-to-as-a-bad-resource-for-learning)). Btw if you want to ask a particular person and want them to get notified about your comment, address them like this: @j1-lee

Comment: I see, thank you. I'll tag people next time

Comment: @j1-lee To stay inside the SO culture may reference to SO-meta: [Why not w3schools.com?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) (as example for "authoritative" resource ️ - same as official Python docs or even [RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/) may be more authoritative than w3schools).

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try to be better when trying to be helpful next time!