# How to rewrite this dictionary definition so PyCharm does not warn?

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

[image]

How to rewrite this dictionary definition so PyCharm does not warn? My understanding is that the form it is currently in is already dictionary literal. I'm using PyCharm 2017.2.4, but I don't think the version matters.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely a dict-literal... Does it go away when you put it all on one line?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Aha! Have you seen this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406242/why-does-pycharms-inspector-complain-about-d) ?

Comment: The problem is not reproducible in 2017.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by

```
my_dict = {
    'key1': 'value1'
}

pass
```

Comment: or my_dict = dict()

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
my_dict = dict( key1 = 'value1' )
```

It's a different notation. Not sure why PyCharm is complaining about what you entered before. But you should also make sure you have the latest edition of PyCharm.
Also, click on the "more..." link (shown in your image) to see what it says. It might even be helpful! :)