# Why is the dict literal syntax preferred over the dict constructor?

Tags: python, dictionary, object-literal

Why is the Python dict constructor slower than the using literal syntax?

After hot debate with my colleague, I did some comparison and got the following statistics:

```
python2.7 -m timeit "d = dict(x=1, y=2, z=3)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.47 usec per loop

python2.7 -m timeit "d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.162 usec per loop
```

What is the reason the constructor is slower? And in what situations, if any, would it be faster?

Comment: Usually this has to do with the fact that `dict` could point to something else. So the interpreter can't make any real optimizations. With the `{}` syntax, it can make those optimizations.

Comment: that is: `dict` is always a genuine function call, whereas `{}` is handled at compile time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [differences between "d = dict()" and "d = {}"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745008/differences-between-d-dict-and-d)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The constructor is slower because it creates the object by calling the `dict()` function, whereas the compiler turns the dict literal into [`BUILD_MAP`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_MAP) bytecode, saving the function call.