# Python: 'list()' or '[]'

Tags: python, syntax

Just wondering: what is the difference in between `list = list()` and `list = []`, and in between `dict()` and `{}`?
If none, which is the most Pythonic?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using the literals in IMHO, is more *pythonic*.

Comment: There's no semantic difference. Literals are more pythonic.

Comment: [What's the difference between list() and `[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33716401/1324033)

Comment: A lot of info out there already. For example, [How to create an empty list in python](https://java2blog.com/create-empty-list-python/)

Comment: The shorter [] and {} is more Pythonic. There is no real difference (as long as the names "list" or "dict" aren't overwritten by something) although the short variants (literals) are slightly faster.

Comment: The literals are more efficient as well; the compiler can allocate the object immediately, before the code runs, rather than waiting until runtime to call whatever the name is bound to. (A compiler will typically not undertake the analysis needed to determine if the name has been rebound.)

Comment: Reiterating [Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745292/5431791) : `dict()` is more "pronounceable", whereas `{}` is faster. Rest depends on opinion, according to Alex Martelli `dict()` is better as it is more explicit.

Comment: Is nobody going to mention that there IS a difference? 'list()' can be used to consume the contents of an iterator or generator, whereas the literal '[]' would just create a list with an iterator reference in the same context.